# What is the easiest way to get a job in quantum computing? Are there any quantum computing hackathons

Tags: job-search, new-job, hiring-process, hiring, business

I've been applying to a lot of jobs involving quantum computing on LinkedIn now but the applications all seem to end up getting lost to the void and I haven't had even one reply from any of them. I was wondering if there is a better more effective way to get a job in this field?

Some background on myself: I have bachelor degrees in physics and astrophysics from UC Berkeley and took some of the first classes there offered in the field of quantum computing. I have mostly had professional experience with implementing post-quantum cryptography protocols and testing if existing ones have vulnerabilities that can be exploited. This sometimes involves implementing proof of concept demos which involve writing code for running quantum algorithms.

Also apologies if this is the wrong board to ask this question, let me know what the best to ask this question is if that is the case.

I'm really passionate about the subject and feel like its where I should be professionally speaking but I don't really see any obvious window to get into the industry.

Some helpful advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you asked anyone in the field for there opinion, like on linked in? What did they say? Have you applied for low enough leveled jobs? A lot of them require a PhD. Have you applied for internships?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can improve your chances:

- Since you have experience related to quantum-computing: Be seen! Do some kind of presentation at a conference about your work. Spend the rest of the conference talking to people who might employ you! (Which might mean missing other interesting presentations.) If you do not think you are not "good enough" yet to compete with other scientists/developers in the field: You do not have to be. You just have to be approachable and understandable enough to impress the *business* people - since they are most likely to hire you.
- Write a book. If you are not good at socializing but good at writing: Publish a small book! No matter if it is good or not: if you can claim to be an "author", some people will attribute much more experience and authority to you. You might even send a copy to any company that might employ you about a months or two in advance. Do not waste years of your life for this, of course: about 200 pages aimed at people with less experience than you (especially business-people) and a few good illustration (see fiver, perhaps) can do the trick and might be achievable in less then half a year even while working.
- Try to contact people within the company. If necessary via linkedin, or even better via personal connections. Try to find out what would stop you from successfully applying there. Or what they are looking out for! Human Resources will be very tight-lipped, but developers might sometimes be friendly and helpful.

One last thing: Make sure there is nothing "blocking" you. Might employers fear you might steal their technology, simply based on your nationality? Did your application-letters conform to the legal and cultural specifications of the target? Does anything else raise a red flag for employers? Consult a professional and make sure there are no such blocks (or, if they are, they are addressed best as you could).